# Is every function in a finite ring is a polynomial function?

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

We known that "Every function can represent as a polynomial function" in Finite field .what  about  in   finite ring. when we consider the polynomial $x^2-1\in\mathbb Z_8[x]$  has $4$ roots $(1,3,5,7) $in $\mathbb Z_8$. By fundamental theorem  of algebra , degree of polynomial and number of roots of the polynomial  must be same(at most). here  degree two polynomial have 4 roots. this violates fundamental theorem. which means polynomial$\nRightarrow$ function in Finite ring. is its converse true  over finite ring?

Comment: If the ring is of finite characteristic then you can express any function as a polynomial

Comment: @learner Really? If $F$ is an infinite field of characteristic $2$, there are $|F|^{|F|}$ functions, but only $|F|$ polynomials. Finiteness is a necessary condition.

Comment: @egreg how can we speak  finite characteristic to infinite field ?

Comment: @egreg  yeah! if $|F|=n$ there are $n^n $ functions  can defined includes constant function. can we treat these constant function as constant polynomial?  if yes, how it reduce $|F|$ alone polynomials?

Comment: @AnithaGandhi Take any finite field $K$ and consider the field of quotients $F$ of $K[X]$. This is an infinite field having the same characteristic as $F$.

Comment: @egreg, thanks for pointing the error.

Answer (score 1):

This fails for all $\Bbb{Z}_m$, $m$ not a prime. Consider any polynomial $f(x)\in\Bbb{Z}_4[x]$. We easily see that $f(0)\equiv f(2)\pmod 2$ as well as $f(1)\equiv f(3)\pmod2$. Therefore it is impossible to get the function $g:\Bbb{Z}_4\to\Bbb{Z}_4, 0\mapsto 1, 1\mapsto0,2\mapsto2, 3\mapsto3$ by evaluating any polynomial.

Comment: See [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/52003/11619),[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/789219/11619) for more.

Comment: Take $f(x)=x^3+2x+1 \in \mathbb{Z}_4[x]$. Then $f(1)=4$ and $f(3)=34$. So $f(1) \not\equiv f(3)$ (mod $4$). Do you mean mod $2$ ?

Comment: Oops. Typo in the second congruence. Thanks @learner.

Comment: For my above example, $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_4$. But I didn't understand the maps $2 \mapsto 2$ and $3 \mapsto 3$. Can you please explain it ?

Comment: If $f(x)\in\Bbb{Z}_4[x]$, then automatically $f(0)\equiv f(2)\pmod2$. So any function $g$ such that $g(0)=1, g(2)=2$ cannot be gotten by evaluating a polynomial. I decided to make the example a permutation, but that is not necessary. $g0)=1$m $g(k)=0$ for all $k\in\Bbb{Z}_4,k\neq0$ is also impossible for a polynomial $g$.